# text-overflow: ellipses does not work when parent width is fixed and child width is dynamic

Tags: html, css

I have a parent `<div>` which has multiple child `span`s. the width of the parent div is fixed, but the width of the child spans can be dynamic. The way I have tried, the text overflow: ellipses does not seem to work on the child.

```
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child1"> Content 1</span>
  <span class="child2"> Content 2</span>
  <span class="child3"> Content 3</span>
</div>


.parent {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r4xbbmyg/).

Answer (score 0):

If the width of the child elements is dynamic, you have to change their style to:

```
span {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;    
}
```

You also have to change the display property of the parent to flex:

```
.parent {
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   max-width: 200px;
   display: flex;
}
```

Comment: But the width of the span is not fixed, Its dynamic. I only know the max-width of the parent element.

Comment: I understand. I edited my answer. You have to add overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;  to the style of the child element  and change the display property of the parent to flex. I tested it in your fiddle and it worked.

Comment: Then it applies the ellipses to all the spans, I want the ellipses to be applied only to the span, which overflows. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: @Kaloyan why are we using flex over here?

Answer (score 0):

[`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) is not an [`inherited`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance) property. This means the value you assign to it applies only to the parent element (`.parent`) but not to its children (`span`).

To fix your issue, simply move that property down to the children. For example (depending on your context) you can code it this way:

```
.parent {  
  border: 1px solid red;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: But the width of the span is not fixed, Its dynamic. I only know the max-width of the parent element.

Comment: It will not work in that case, wherever you put that property. Your `span` elements must have a fixed length @MananShah

Comment: Thats the problem! The span are of variable length, while the width of the parent is fixed. There might be a flex solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .parent {
      max-width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }

   
    <div class="parent">
      <span class="child1"> Content 1</span>
      <span class="child2"> Content 2</span>
      <span class="child3"> Content 3 Content 3 Content 3</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: The spans are inline blocks and not inline elements. If you make them inline -block it does not work.

Comment: so you need spans in separate lines?

Comment: No same line, but they have some margin top and bottom of their own. So i can't make them inline, they have to be inline block.

Comment: Ya, but if you use inline-block, the text-overflow: ellipses wont work

Comment: Ellipsis will work, when u give inline-block to span class "child1".

Answer (score -1):

It's working i guess.

```css
.parent {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child1"> Content 1</span>
  <span class="child2"> Content 2</span>
  <span class="child3"> Content 3 Content 3 Content 3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I want text-overflow: ellipsis; to work. Right know its not showing ellipses on overflow.